# Dates locale in Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm storing dates in Google Cloud Datastore using the Go client library. The dates are managed in the go code as time.Time type. What is a bit unclear from the documentation is how the dates are retrieved. The docs says they are retrieved as local time and my question is: "local time of the server or the client?"

Also, I would expect the date to be retrieved with the same locale as saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datastore package sets the [time's location](https://godoc.org/time#Time.Location) to the [local location](https://godoc.org/time#Local) of the Go program.

More details:

Times are saved as Unix nanoseconds in the datastore service.  The location is not saved.

The datastore package uses the [time.Unix](https://godoc.org/time#Unix) function to convert Unix nanoseconds to a `time.Time` value.  The time.Unix function sets the location to the [local location](https://godoc.org/time#Local).

Comment: So the time information gets sent as unix timestamp and then marshalled into a go time object by the datastore client library. It's the datastore client library setting the location to the local location of the server running that code?